# Closing questions tagged with looking-for-hosting?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Now that we have this community wiki question: [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements), shouldn't someone go through the questions tagged with [looking-for-hosting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looking-for-hosting) and close the duplicate questions?

Answer (score 1):

Working on it - identified about 10 (w/no accepted answer, some open since 2010) for closure.

Please feel free flag any further questions which fit this criteria for moderator attention.